# How can I get link for HTML files from Google Drive?

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

I am writing an iOS application, and I have some HTML files stored on Google Drive. I would like to retrieve the HTML file's links.

Any idea to get the HTML link from Google Drive?

Comment: Are you tagging this as Objective-C because you want the answer in some sort of Objective-C context?

Comment: @nathanwhite because i want to add that url to my iOS project....

Comment: If that's the case, you really should state that in your question. Also, your question is very vague: do you want to retrieve the HTML file link programmatically, or just via Google Drive. Also, are there a finite number of HTML files, or will there be more later?

Comment: @nathanwhite ya i have finite number of files.and want the link of that files so that i can load that html to the webview.

Comment: So, if you have a finite number of files, all stored on (I assume) your personal Google Drive account, why don't you just hardcode it?

Comment: @nathanwhite our client requirement is like that so we cant hardcode it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to hardcode the values of the file's URL, the only alternative is to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) on iOS.